# PHP soap - Unable to pass object as parameter of soap function

Tags: php, wcf, soap

I am attempting to interact with a WCF4 service using PHP SoapClient.

I have successfully created the client object and connected. I can list functions and types using ->getFunctions(), ->getTypes().

I'm trying to run one of our custom methods (SignIn), which returns an object containing 2 strings (sessionID & sitename). This method requires one parameter which is a custom object type (SignInDetails), which in turn contains 3 strings ('Sitename', 'Username', 'Password' ).

My first class is used to build the SignInDetails object containing these details. Second class runs our custom method and passes the object as a parameter however the method always responds with:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [a:InternalServiceFault] Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
class clsLoginCredentials {

    public $Sitename = null;
    public $Username = null;
    public $Password = null;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->Sitename = 'test';
        $this->Username = 'test';
        $this->Password = 'test';

    }

}


class clsloginSession {

    private $client = null;
    private $objLoginCredentials = null;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->objLoginCredentials = new clsLoginCredentials;
        $this->client = getClient();
    }

    public function loginSessionContractData() {

        return $this->client->SignIn( $this->objLoginCredentials );

    }

}

$testSession = new clsloginSession;
$testSessionData = $testSession->loginSessionContractData();

var_dump( $testSessionData );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the issue. Soap expects the object to be passed in via an associated array with a key that reflects the parameter name as below:

```
public function loginSessionContractData() {

    return $this->client->SignIn( array( 'signInDetails' => $this->objLoginCredentials ) );

}
```